# Should this be the responsibility of the controller or the domain?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework, design-patterns

In my application I have Users, Organisations and Employees.  There are domain objects for each of these, and database mappers.

When a User initially sets up an Organisation, I want to automatically create an Employee record for that User/Organisation combination.  (The type of record will be Owner).  Basically this comes down to two database inserts: one for Organisation, the other for Employee.

I can see two ways to go about this:

1. The controller can create the new Organisation object and use a mapper, `orgMapper::insert($newOrg)`, to persist it.  With that done it can then create the new Employee object and again use a mapper, `employeeMapper::insert($newOwner)`, for persistence.
2. The controller can create the new Organisation object, and this object does the rest of the work itself.  It would call `orgMapper::insert($this)`, and with the key which is returned would then create and persist the new Employee object.

There seems to be a number of benefits in the second approach: the business logic (i.e. an employee/Owner record for each new Organisation) is embedded in the model, and the controller is skinnier.  The only reason I hesitate is that this means my domain is becoming dependent on my mapper.

I would use a factory in the domain to get the mapper, so all coupling would come down to a single point.  Does this make the dependency acceptable?  Or do I have a deeper design issue?

I have read a bit about a service layer.  Perhaps this is where I should be looking?

I am using PHP and Zend Framework

Your thoughts are much appreciated.  My cat and I have exhausted our own ideas...

Comment: I'd look more into a service layer of some type who's sole job is governing db referential integrity, and take that job out of the individual data mappers.  At the very least, even though the code needed to make this happen would be very short, it should give you reusable coded rules for managing other projects which work on the same data set.  IMHO.  Hopefully I made sense.  But, there could be db-level functionality you could be missing out on depending on what db software you're using.  What database are you using?

Comment: @bob-the-destroyer, I'm using mySql

Comment: what engine for these tables? Myisam or innodb?

Comment: well then, you've got foreign key support, so db normalization isn't completely dependent on your PHP application.  Still, I'd say continue to look into a service layer.

Comment: Indeed, I'm with @bob-the-destroyer. I try to keep my controller looking as much like a "traffic cop" as possible. If there are several things to be done in an action - models to be created, db writes, emails to be sent - I prefer to aggregate them into a service class so that the controller only has to call one method on the service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since I am not a ZF user (and have been avoiding it), maybe my solution would not apply.

Data mappers are not supposed to work with just a single table in database. Instead, when you are storing the new `Organization` entry (and i guess the `Organization` instance contains a collection of `Employee` objects), the mapper also should create all the entries for the Employees, and the accompanying data in `OrganizationEmpoyees` table.

The short answer: **neither, storage is responsibility of mapper.**

If I misunderstood the DB structure, and how it relates to *"(..) Employee record for that User/Organisation combination"* and the the `Employee` domain objects are completely separate from `Organization`, then the 1st of your solutions would be acceptable.

As for adding service on top of domain objects and mappers, that would be a good idea. Because you have been leaking domain logic inside the controller already. Seems like a bad thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you what I do in cases like this. Anytime I need to take a pile of data and build more then one object from it, I dump the whole mess to another model (maybe a service layer, I don't know) and sort out the objects away from the controller. I just use controllers to grab data and send it somewhere else (view or model).

For example I want to save some data from my music collection, the data is currently in a csv file. My controller parses the csv file and puts each line of data into an array which I forward to a class method that sorts the data into objects and saves it to the database.
(Plz note this method is preliminary and requires some tweaking and adjustment)

```
//FROM class Application_Model_Tag
public function saveTags() {
        //TODO implement instantiation of Domain Models instead of passing arrays to mappers
        $trackMapper  = new Music_Model_Mapper_Track();
        $artistMapper = new Music_Model_Mapper_Artist();
        $albumMapper  = new Music_Model_Mapper_Album();

        if (isset($this->_hash)) {
            //see if track already exists by comparing hashs
            $trackRow = $trackMapper->fetchByColumn('hash', $this->getHash());
            //if track does not exist
            if (is_null($trackRow)) {
                //save the artist
                $artistData = array(
                    'name' => $this->getArtist()
                );
                //see it the artist exists by name
                $artistRow = $artistMapper->fetchByColumn('name', $this->getArtist());
                //does artist exist?
                if (is_null($artistRow)) {
                    $artistRow = $artistMapper->save($artistData);
                }

                //Save the Album Data
                //does the album exist?
                $albumRow = $albumMapper->fetchByColumn('name', $this->getAlbum());
                //if yes
                if (is_null($albumRow)) {
                    $albumData = array(
                        'name'      => $this->getAlbum(),
                        'artist_id' => $artistRow->id,
                        'art'       => $this->getAlbum() . '.jpg',
                        'year'      => $this->getYear()
                    );
                    //get album row
                    $albumRow = $albumMapper->save($albumData);
                }
                //Save track data
                $trackData = array(
                    'title'     => $this->getTitle(),
                    'filename'  => $this->getFilename(),
                    'path'      => $this->getPath(),
                    'format'    => $this->getFormat(),
                    'genre'     => $this->getGenre(),
                    'artist_id' => $artistRow->id,
                    'album_id'  => $albumRow->id,
                    'track'     => $this->getTrack(),
                    'play_time' => $this->getPlay_time(),
                    'hash'      => $this->getHash()
                );
                //save track data
                $trackMapper->save($trackData);
            }
        } else {
            return;
        }
    }
```

I hope this helps, and please forgive the crudity of the example.